# Problem with C program never returning from strtok() function

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am working on a university assignment and I've been wracking my head around a weird problem where my program calls `strtok` and never returns.

My code looks like:

```
int loadMenuDataIn(GJCType* menu, char *data)
{
   char *lineTokenPtr;
   int i;

   lineTokenPtr = strtok(data, "\n"); 
   while (lineTokenPtr != NULL) { 

   /* ... */

   }

}
```

I've looked up a bunch of sites on the web, but I cant see anything wrong with the way that I am using `strtok` and I cant determine why it would my code would get stuck on the line `lineTokenPtr = strtok(data, "\n");`

Can anyone help me shed some light on this?

(Using OSX and Xcode if it makes any difference)

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger and can you verify that is the line that's not returning? If so, what is `data`? Is it properly terminated, not Unicode, etc?

Comment: If you want to keep using the string you are passing to `strtok`, you must create a copy of it, because both `strtok` and `strsep` will modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked the contents of the argument? is it \0 terminated?

the argument that you pass, is it writeable memory? strtok writes to the buffer that it gets as first argument when it tokenizes the string.

IOW if you write

```
char* mystring = "hello\n";

strtok(mystring,"\n"); // you get problems
```

Comment: Hang on, you mean it tries to alter my original input string!?

Comment: yes it does. you can get a hint of that since the first argument of strtok is declared char* not const char*

Comment: The signature of strtok is `char * strtok (char* str, const char* delimiters);`. The lack of const for your input string should tell you that it might be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtok()` replaces the actual token delimiting symbols in the character string with null (i.e., `\0`) chars, and returns a pointer to the start of the token in the string.  So after repeated calls to `strtok()` with a newline delimiting symbol, a string buffer that looked like

```
"The fox\nran over\nthe hill\n"
```

in memory will be literally modified in-place and turned into

```
"The fox\0ran over\0the hill\0"
```

with `char` pointers returned from `strtok()` that point to the strings `the fox\0`, `ran over\0`, and `the hill\0`.  No new memory is allocated ... the original string memory is modified in-place, which means it's important not to pass a string literal that is of type `const char*`.